# Why do I get NullPointerException when trying to access resource file?

Tags: java, jar, resources

I want to make so a file in the program is packaged in the jar file because it is needed in my program. It is the firebase credentials file. I read that I need to add it to the resource folder but now I cannot access it because I get NullPointerException. I think the path is valid and everything seems okay but I get null every time. Here is the code:

> ```
> ClassLoader classLoader = EmailSender.class.getClassLoader();
> File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("/parkingsystem-cf164-firebase-adminsdk-5jjuk-2be72bfcce.json")).getFile());
> ```

And here is the code structure:
[code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2SN2.png)

If there is another method to add file to jar I am open to hear it, it is just what I found on the Internet but it does not work for me. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: So apparently it works when the `/` is removed but then I need to convert it to FileInputStream and there I get FileNotFoundExcpetion. The rest of the code:

```
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FirebaseOptions options = null;
    try {
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the leading slash `/`? Also does that NPE occur during local development or after it was packaged into a .jar?

Comment: Hi! The NPE occurs during both local development and with the jar. When I removed the '/' it manages to get the file but then I need it to be converted to FileInputStream which throws FileNotFoundException and it says "The system cannot find the path specified".

Comment: On the "why do I get the NPE?": you very likely get it on the `getFile()` call (need to guess since you didn't share the details) which would be because `getResource()` returns `null` due to the resource not being found. If you leave out the slash and thus returns the resource this should be the way to go. Please share the details on the `FileNotFoundException`, i.e. how you are trying to get the stream. Did you try `getResourceAsStream(...)` for this?

Comment: Why not do `OutputStream os 
= Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/parkingsystem-cf164-firebase-adminsdk-5jjuk-2be72bfcce.json"));`?

Comment: I edited the question with the added code you can check it out now.